# Trying to avoid subqueries with prepared statements with MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I'm trying to understand how to build a valid and optimized query without having a subquery in an INSERT statement.

I have 3 tables:
- users (userId, name, surname, ....., ...., and deptId)
- shifts (shiftId, ....., ....., ...)
- departments (deptId, departments)

In the registration form the user is requested to choose his dept.
I would like to insert in users.deptId the id number taken from the departments.deptId relatively to the office choosen.
As soon as I figure it out how to make it, I will transform the following query into a prepared statement one.

Here is the shortened version:

```
INSERT INTO users (userId, name , surname, deptId)
VALUES 
('','$name', '$surname', (select deptId from departments where dept = '$choosen_dept'));
```

Is there any way to avoid this ugly subquery?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with subqueries.

Comment: However, why not have the person select the deptid as the value? then you can just insert that.

Comment: @DigitalChris Thanks but I think any user would not like to choose from a html select something like: 1, 2, 3, 4...the reason I'm doing this relation with the depts table is for normalization..

Comment: Look at INSERT INTO SELECT syntax

Comment: @user3159187 NO no no, you create a select list with value =  the id and text is the name. They select the name, and you pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, surname, deptId)
    SELECT '$name', '$surname', deptId
    FROM departments WHERE dept = '$chosen_dept';"
```